# Android - Set vertical position of RecyclerView without scrolling?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview

I want to set the vertical position of the recycler view at the time of setting the adapter.  This is proving more difficult than I intended. Below is the relevant code:

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(),provider.getItems(),analyticsHandler, null);
myRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
myRecyclerView.invalidate();

if (pos < adapter.getItemCount()) {
    myRecyclerView.getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(pos);
}
```

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "vertical position"? I would assume you mean positioning the `RecyclerView` as needed on its y axis, but your code example seems to suggest you want to set the position inside the `RecyclerView` to a particular item.

Comment: I want to set the `RecyclerView` on a particular item with the index `pos`. The `RecyclerView` has a vertical orientation. EDIT: by index I mean the adapter view position.

Comment: Do you know the position of the item ahead of time? Your code example does not show where you determine the value of  `pos`. Regardless, `.scrollToPosition()` is the correct method to scroll to an item with a given position. I am not sure why you are calling `.invalidate()` on the `RecyclerView`, but it is not needed for what you are asking here.

Comment: I'm resetting the adapter here, so invalidate is needed to redraw the view.

Comment: Resetting the adapter has nothing to do with `.invalidate()`, if you want to reset and clear an adapter, clear its dataset and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Comment: Right. The point is to redraw the view, not the adapter. The data set isn't changing -- the adapter is.

Comment: Again, redrawing the view accomplishes nothing for your use case, unless there is something you are trying to do that you have not included in your question.